# Найти самого старшего сотрудника

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица работников

```
CREATE TABLE worker (
worker_id       INT,
last_name       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
first_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
middle_name     VARCHAR(30),
birth_date      DATE NOT NULL,
dismis_date     DATE,
FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES department(department_id) ON DELETE SET NULL);
```

И таблица департаментов

```
CREATE TABLE department (
department_id   INT,
department      VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(department_id));
```

В поле dismis_date установлена дата увольнения сотрудника, или значение null. Как мне получить самых старших из не уволенных сотрудников (dismis_date)? Например следующего сотрудника который который младше самого старшего, но в поле dismis_date у него установлено значение null.
Мой запрос

```
SELECT cr.*
FROM worker w
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(birth_date) max_age, department_id
    FROM worker 
    GROUP BY department_id
) w1
    ON w.department_id = w1.department_id AND w.birth_date = w1.max_age;
```

Возвращает старших сотрудников совместно с уже уволенными.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY birth_date) rnk
    FROM worker
    WHERE dismis_date IS NULL )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: `dismis_date IS NULL`, так как нужны еще не уволенные

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Да, точно. Ща поправим. Готово. Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо.